# How to get access token from WSO2 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wso2

I use Laravel to call API from WSO2 API Manager but I get an error message:

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900902</ams:code><ams:message>Missing Credentials</ (truncated...)
```

I know root cause is because of access token. How can I get access token from WSO2 via laravel.

Answer (score 0):

What is the grant type you are using to generate the token ? And are you providing the required authentication parameters (ex: username, password, client id, etc depending on the grant type you use) along with your request?

Please check https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Token+API for more info.

Comment: grant type by client credential and using client id and client secret